# 11g SUM BY two columns returning different data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sum, obiee

Oracle 11g is giving me a headache and I am not able to find any answer that's relevant to my question.

I am trying to calculate revenue *per work order*, this is not available as a calculated field and is only available through a calculation.

Columns available:

- Item code
- Item price (int)
- Quantity (int)
- Charge? (0 when not charged, -1 when charged)

There's been made a difference between "Labour" and "Materials", both of which can create a charge for the customer.

My code right now is as follows:

```
SUM(
    CASE WHEN ("BOL/BOM Items"."BOLBOM Code") IN ('1-845413','1-845911','1-845912', '1-MW-222') THEN
    0
    ELSE

        ("Workorder BOL Items"."Quantity MW (BOL)" * -("Workorder BOL Items"."Charge MW (BOL)")) * "Workorder BOL Items"."Price Incl BTW MW (BOL)"
        +
        ("Workorder BOM Items"."Quantity MW (BOM)" * -("Workorder BOM Items"."Charge MW (BOM)")) * "Workorder BOM Items"."Price Incl BTW MW (BOM)"

    END

    BY
    "Work Orders"."CallID"
)
```

This adds up all the charges for each work order perfectly, but **only** when the column for "Item code" is added to the query. It doesn't matter when I exclude it from the view.

An example is a result that returns 112 (2x16 (labour) + 1x 80 (material)) when the column is added, but only 80 when the item code column is not present.

Is there a way this could work without the query asking for the additional column?

Below is a sample data set with the column "CalcRevenue" being the desired result.

```
CallID  BOLBOM Code CalcRevenue Quantity MW (BOM)   Charge MW (BOM) Price Incl BTW MW (BOM) Quantity MW (BOL)   Charge MW (BOL) Price Incl BTW MW (BOL)
0010000065554342    1-SW-004    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0010000065554342    1-SW-006    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0010000065554342    1-SW-008    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0010000065554342    1-SW-012    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0010000066233542    1-845921    112 1   -1  80,00   0   0   0,00
0010000066233542    1-MW-009    112 0   0   0,00    2   -1  16,00
0010000066233542    1-MW-222    112 0   0   0,00    2   -1  0,00
0010000066233542    1-SW-044    112 0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-842753    0   1   0   90,75   0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-SW-102    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-SW-104    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-SW-105    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-SW-108    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-SW-109    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
0050001100208165    3-SW-110    0   0   0   0,00    0   0   0,00
```

Each CallID can have multiple "BOLBOM Code", which in turn have the Charge/Quantity and Price columns.

This is what happens to the same data if I remove the "BOLBOM" (and related) columns.

```
CallID  CalcRevenue
0010000065554342    0
0010000066233542    208
0050001100208165    0
```

I'd like to calculate the revenue per CallID (work order) - Which is calculated as follows:

```
Revenue = (Quantity * -(Charge)) * Price
```

Charge will be -1 when it is charged to the customer, 0 otherwise. 
It is calculated on the "BOLBOM" level of the order, but should be SUMmed to the "Work Order" level.

Comment: It means you want to store 112 (as per your example) in one column in a table.

Comment: Please give the DDL for your tables, a sample dataset and the expected output for that dataset. As it stands, it is very difficult to try to work out what you are doing as the "columns available" do not match the column names used in your query and you have an expected output with no data to work out where that came from.

Comment: it would be easier for us to understand if you edited your question to provide create table and insert statements, along with the expected output and the logic behind how the expected output was derived. That way, we have a much better chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Also the full query is likely helpful; knowing what your group by statement is will be helpful

Comment: Have updated with some examples. Hopefully this clarifies my intentions and available data. As I only have rights to the presentation layer I can't provide CREATE and INSERT statements. Thanks so far for your help.